# How can i setStyleSheet in QML?(only QML no C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I want to create a custom Scrollbar.Like this.

[image]

This is my code, i want to use ScrollBar component in Qml.

```
Rectangle {
id: frame
clip: true
width: 160
height: 160
border.color: "black"
anchors.centerIn: parent

Text {
    id: content
    text: "ABC"
    font.pixelSize: 160
    x: -hbar.position * width
    y: -vbar.position * height
}

ScrollBar {
    id: vbar
    hoverEnabled: true
    active: hovered || pressed
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    size: frame.height / content.height
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
  } 
}
```

In my case, i want to create with **my Scrollbar image**.

I tried「**source: "./bar.bng"** 」,but it said ScrollBar haven't have the parameter "source". How can i use custom image.

Comment: Theres no hint in the manual saying the QML scrollbar types are actually using any image resources. They are made up of primitives (e.g. rectangles). To customize the scrollbar, reimplement it. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-scrollbar-scrollbar-qml.html for how the default scrollbars are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stylesheets (in a form of .qss files, as used for QWidget's) are **not used for QML**.

[Here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling) are examples of how you can implement them though.

For your exact use-case, check out [Customizing ScrollBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar)

Comment: Thank you,that's what i want! ScrollBar consists of two visual items: background and content item.In my case just set the content item as image.